How to use an external logback.xml
I need to log using an external logback.xml file.
Note: I have a spring boot app. If I keep the logback.xml file inside src/main/resources then all works fine. But when I supply it like
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=./logback.xml -jar app1.jar 

then the log file gets created but it remains empty i.e. capture no logs. I am using logback.xml file as below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
     
    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>MyAppt1.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
         
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>MyAppt1-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
     
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</configuration>


One thing to try - double-check that file is actually being used.  An easy way to do so is to break the syntax of the file and run it to see if an error is reported.

Or do <configuration debug="true">

Test spring-boot 3.3.0
java -jar app1.jar  --logging.config=file:./logback.xml

pom.xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

HelloWorldController.java
package com.example.demo_ext_log;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldController.class);

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld(@RequestParam(value = "msg", defaultValue = "World") String msg) {
        logger.info(">>>> Received request with msg: {}", msg);
        return "Hello, " + msg + "!";
    }
}

application.properties (default value)
spring.application.name=demo-ext-log

I directly used the same content as your logback.xml file to test.
It will output the contents of logging to MyAppt1.log

you need to add the file path in application like this:
application.properties
logging.config=./logback.xml

then start the jar
java --spring.config.location=file:./config/  -jar app1.jar 

